# Reload flask page after form submission success with JQuery

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I have a page that uses a form with POST method that passes a file to my flask application. I have read that my `app.route` cannot handle both a `send_file` and a redirect. So my workaround is to refresh the page after the post request is successful.

Here is my HTML with my script at the bottom:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block head %}
    <!-- {# <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/leaf.css') }}"> #} -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/base.css') }}"> -->
    {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    <div id="vo_budget_file_settings">
        {# <a href="/generatecleanbudgetfile" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Final CRO Budget File</a> #}
        <p>Please upload the final CRO budget File</p>
        <form class="" action="/generatecleanbudgetfile" method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data>
            <input type="file" name="data_file" accept=".xls, .xlsx, .xlsm"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Begin Format" onclick="loading();"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- funtion to show css spinner on button click -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loading(){
          $(".loader").show();     
        }
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Reload page 60 seconds after form submission
        $("vo_budget_file_settings").onsubmit = setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = "/bugetformatter"; 
            }, 60000);
            console.log(window.location);
        </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Here is my app:

```
@app.route('/bugetformatter')
def data_request_portal():
    return render_template('CROBudgetFormatter.html', title='CRO Budget Formatting Tool')

@app.route('/generatecleanbudgetfile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def clean_budget():
    file = request.files.get('data_file')
    app.logger.info('Conversion has started')
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            file = request.files.get('data_file')
            file.seek(0)
            buffer = budget_cleaner(file)
            buffer.seek(0)
            app.logger.info('Conversion Complete')
            return send_file(
            buffer,
            as_attachment=True,
            attachment_filename=f'stripped_budget_{dt.today().strftime("%m.%d.%Y")}.xlsx',
            mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
            )
    except:
        return render_template('error_type.html', title='Unable to process uploaded budget.')
```

## Question:

Is there a script that behaves like a callback and will only reload the window once the request is completed and my file downloads to the browser?

Right now I'm using the 60 timer to reset after the form is submitted, but I would like it to be tied to the file download just in case the job takes longer than that.

Answer (score 0):

your app needs to be

```
@app.route('/generatecleanbudgetfile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def clean_budget():
    file = request.files.get('data_file')
    app.logger.info('Conversion has started')
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            file = request.files.get('data_file')
            file.seek(0)
            buffer = budget_cleaner(file)
            buffer.seek(0)
            app.logger.info('Conversion Complete')
            return send_file(
            buffer,
            as_attachment=True,
            attachment_filename=f'stripped_budget_{dt.today().strftime("%m.%d.%Y")}.xlsx',
            mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
            )
            return 1
    except:
        return render_template('error_type.html', title='Unable to process uploaded budget.')
```

and your html file needs to be:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
        {% block head %}
        <!-- {# <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/leaf.css') }}"> #} -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/base.css') }}"> -->
        {% endblock %}
        {% block content %}
        <div id="vo_budget_file_settings">
            {# <a href="/generatecleanbudgetfile" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Final CRO Budget File</a> #}
            <p>Please upload the final CRO budget File</p>
            <form class="formdata" action="/generatecleanbudgetfile" method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data>
                <input type="file" name="data_file" accept=".xls, .xlsx, .xlsm"/>
                <input type="button" value="Begin Format" onclick="submit();"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- funtion to show css spinner on button click -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $("form.formdata").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData(this);  
               $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: '/generatecleanbudgetfile',
                      data: formData,
                      cache: false,
                      contentType: false,
                      processData: false,
                      success: function(data) {
           window.location.reload();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error occured');
            window.location.reload();
        }
        
       });     
      });
      </script>
      {% endblock %}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I appreciate the response. What does the `return 1` do in the app? When I add to my code it's shaded out like it's not going to get executed.

Comment: Also, when I tested the jquery I got this error in the inspector: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.
    at loading (bugetformatter:47)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (bugetformatter:40)`

Comment: return helps to check the data in ajax.
Sorry you need to provide this parameter.. i have update the example. please check.

Comment: For some reason, I'm not having success with this code. I suspect this because the `return 1` isn't executing. From everything I read the route can only return 1 object